# React, Update String in useState does not work as expected

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a typing efect, but the 2nd letter is not added.

For example:

I want to write "Hello World" and it displays "Hllo World".

my code:

```js
export default function Error({ errorMsg }) {
    const [errorString, setErrorString] = useState("");
    let i = 0;

    useEffect(() => {
        writeError();
    }, []);

    function writeError() {
        let timer = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 25 + 1)) + 25;

        setTimeout(() => {
            if (i < errorMsg.length) {
                setErrorString(errorString => ([
                    ...errorString,
                    errorMsg.charAt(i)
                ]));
                i++;
                return writeError();
            }
        }, timer);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div id="wrp">
                <div>{errorString}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Why does the error only occur with the 2nd character, no matter how long the string is?

## Edit

Thanks for the solutions, but the solution of @DecPK is the best in my opinion

fixed code:

```js
export default function Error({ errorMsg }) {
    const [errorString, setErrorString] = useState("");
    let i = 0;

    useEffect(() => {
        writeError();
    }, []);

    function writeError() {
        let timer = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 25 + 1)) + 25;

        setTimeout(() => {
            if (i < errorMsg.length) {
                setErrorString(errorString => ([
                    ...errorString,
                    errorMsg.charAt(i++) // <-- Answer from @DecPK
                ]));
                return writeError();
            }
        }, timer);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div id="wrp">
                <div>{errorString}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: If you do add `i++` in the statement itself then it will work but don't know the reason `setErrorString((errorString) => [...errorString, errorMsg.charAt(i++)]);`

Comment: Oh ok, thanks ️, as long as it works i don't care why ️

Comment: I've just posted my answer, so it would be shortest answer. 

Comment: @Jake so according to your code, you have at most 1 of these `Error` components at the time on your entire page, and the `errorMsg` never changes. Is that correct? Seems kind of limited in its usage/usefulness.

Comment: @Thomas This page is used to display several error messages. That's why I pass errorMsg and don't just use a constant or so. I like animations and with a little css this will be a little more appealing

Comment: And this is not the page as it will be later, there is still a little (style and function) added, it was only important to me first to fix this writing effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from @DecPK

This is a React functional component that renders an error message with a typing effect. Here is a commented version of the code:

```js
// Import React and the useState and useEffect hooks
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

// Define the Error component as the default export of this module
export default function Error({ errorMsg }) {

  // Define a state variable "errorString" and a function "setErrorString" to update it
  const [errorString, setErrorString] = useState("");

  // Define a variable "i" to keep track of the index of the current character being typed
  let i = 0;

  // Use the useEffect hook to trigger the writeError function once, when the component is first mounted
  useEffect(() => {
    writeError();
  }, []);

  // Define the writeError function to update the errorString state variable with a new character every few milliseconds
  function writeError() {

    // Generate a random timeout between 25ms and 100ms
    let timer = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 25 + 1)) + 25;

    // Use the setTimeout function to wait for the random timeout before updating the errorString state variable with the next character
    setTimeout(() => {

      // Check if there are more characters to type
      if (i < errorMsg.length) {

        // Update the errorString state variable by appending the next character to it
        setErrorString(errorString => ([
          ...errorString,
          errorMsg.charAt(i++) // Get the character at the current index and increment i
        ]));

        // Call the writeError function again to type the next character after another random timeout
        return writeError();
      }
    }, timer);
  }

  // Render the component by returning a div with an id "wrp" and another div that displays the errorString state variable
  return (
    <div>
      <div id="wrp">
        <div>{errorString}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In summary, this component uses the useState and useEffect hooks to update the error message with a typing effect, using the setTimeout function to wait for a random timeout between each character.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The issue with updating a string in useState in React is that you cannot update a string directly like you can with other types such as numbers or booleans. Strings are immutable, meaning that once they are created, they cannot be modified. Therefore, any updates to a string variable create a new string and assign it to the variable.

To update a string in useState, you can use the set function provided by the useState hook, passing in the new string value as an argument. For example:

```
const [myString, setMyString] = useState('Hello world');

// Updating the string value using set function
setMyString('Hello React');
```

In the example above, the setMyString function updates the value of the myString state variable to 'Hello React'. When using setMyString to update the string value, you should make sure to always pass a new string as the argument, even if it has the same value as the previous string. This is because React will only re-render the component if the state value reference changes.

Here's an example of updating a string value using setMyString in response to a button click:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [myString, setMyString] = useState('Hello world');

  function handleClick() {
    setMyString('Hello React');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{myString}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Update string</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this example, clicking the "Update string" button will update the myString state variable to 'Hello React' and cause the component to re-render with the new string value.

Comment: As I understand it, the OP wants to stagger the output so the characters appear one at a time with a small delay in between. This doesn't achieve that

Answer (score 0):

My Answer:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Error({ errorMsg }) {
    const [errorString, setErrorString] = useState("");
    let i = 0;


    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => writeError(), 200);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, []);

    function writeError() {
        setErrorString(errorMsg.substring(0, i));
        i++;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div id="wrp">
                <div>{errorString}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Please try to execute this.

Comment: This is an improvement, but still has 2 flaws: OP doesn't want a fixed interval, but a somewhat staggered one between 25 and 100ms. Second, this never stops. It will call setErrorString with the entire string every 200ms until the component is unmounted.

Comment: Also, there are issues with `writeError` being used before it is defined, and the `useEffect` hook being implicitly dependent on `i` and `errorMsg`. It could be re-written as `useEffect(() => {
    let i = 0;

    function writeError() {
      setErrorString(errorMsg.substring(0, i));
      i++;
    }
    
    const interval = setInterval(() => writeError(), 200);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [errorMsg]);`

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I've totally understood what issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the solution below. This component is responsible for managing it's `cursor` state. It then calculates the text to show in render using the `errorMsg` prop. This is the React way.
[Sandbox demo available](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-joana-o96d0y?file=/src/App.js:51-553)

```js
export function Error({ errorMsg }) {
  const [cursor, setCursor] = React.useState(0);
  const randomDelay = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 25 + 1)) + 25;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!(cursor <= errorMsg.length)) return;
    const id = setTimeout(() => setCursor(cursor + 1), randomDelay);
    return () => clearTimeout(id);
  }, [cursor, errorMsg.length, randomDelay]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="wrp">
        <div>{errorMsg.substr(0, cursor)}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```